# Prove that {→} is not a complete set

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I have an idea on how to prove a set with 2 connectives but I've never done any example with a set of one element. Assuming {$\land, \lor, \lnot$} is a complete set, how can I show that {→} is not a complete set?
Can i use truth table to disprove it?

Comment: @Antt here is a hint: consider the monotonicity of each of the arguments of the $\rightarrow$ connective.

Comment: Try to prove that with the use of $\rightarrow $ only, it is impossible to obtain $\lnot.$

Comment: Check [these conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness).

Comment: Hint: $\{\to, \lnot\}$ is a complete set